# Should an answer that fixes an irrelevant typo be removed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-answer

Someone posted a question with a small typo in the code.The typo was unrelated to the question being asked and was edited out almost immediately. Before the typo was fixed, someone posted an answer pointing out an error caused by the typo.

I felt that the answer did not really address the question being asked and at best belonged in the comments. [This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378397/9614249).

I flagged as not an answer but the flag was disputed with 3 reviewers saying the answer looks good and one reviewer recommending deletion. If my memory serves me correctly the answer has even received some up votes since my flag, despite the answer making no sense to anyone reading the question as it is now.

What is the correct action to take in this circumstance? Was my flag justified?

Comment: (for quick reference: the answerer have ~31k rep and so can vote to close as typo)

Comment: That answer doesn't look like fixing a typo but more like saying OP missed a statement in his code. (I intentionally only focus on the answer and not it's comments) And you can always vote on the answer. In this case it would be a downvote meaning _"This answer is not useful"_

Comment: @AndréKool I did vote on the answer. I do think the answer is not useful, but I also feel this does not answer the question and should be a comment instead. That is why I flagged as Not An Answer

Comment: You probably assumed it was a typo in the question.  But it is far more likely that it was a mistake in his program.  Given that the compiler will always tell him about that.  And of course we always assume that questioners copy/paste the snippet from their programming editor.  His answer is in fact a much better explanation than the highly upvoted one, which does not provide any explanation for the observed behavior at all.

Comment: @HansPassant The question is about dealing with files and gives output experienced by the current solution. If the typo were actually an error in the program there would be no output as the program wouldn't compile. Even so, the answer does not address the actual question which is "*How to skip a file when scanning files in a directory*".

Comment: Well, that was my point.  Apparently his full program did have a targetLen variable, it would not compile otherwise.  He went for the RTFM answer because it was too embarrassing to admit.  Not that I'm all that convinced, the typo in the program output is nails on a black-board by itself.  SO contributors have no defense against such horrid sloppiness, we need to demand that questioners do a better job of it.  Copy/paste does not require any skills.

Comment: If you quickly check [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19749391), then only one with 10k+ identify the problem, others probably don't have enough experience yet, or maybe they were convinced by whopping 30k+ reputation of answerer (reviewers are always afraid to fail audit). From my point of view you did everything correctly: flagging the question and asking on meta. Keep doing just like that.

Comment: @HansPassant, you are not defending the answerer, do you?

Comment: Yes, it should be deleted, but it's still an answer (so I was told :)). The accepted answer doesn't do such a good job either. If you have to paste the manual as HTML, closing as duplicate of "how to read a directory" would have been a better choice.